# How do I set the field values of one collection to the field values of another collection via a reference field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

MongoDB:

Assuming that I have collection A with fields `[_id, foo]` and B with fields `[_id, refId, bar]`.

I would like to set `A.foo` to `B.bar`, for every matching record where `B._refId == A._id`

In relational DB this would be a simple UPDATE through JOIN.

In MongoDB, it seems like I have to fetch all of A and B, and iterate through them and invoke a compare and update function on each pass. That seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Basically, I am hoping to find a better way than the following:

```
A.find().forEach(function setFooToBar(anA){
    //find the matching B.bar value for anA, and update anA
    //seems terribly inefficient
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage $lookup assuming you're using a recent version of MongoDB.

Link: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#example

*Example:*

```
db.a.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "b",
      localField: "bar",
      foreignField: "foo",
      as: "foobar"
    }
} 
])
```

Hope this helps!